# DataTable search by Global filter on Prime faces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

This is My complete code. i want global searchin instead of individual column search.
please any one help me

```
<p:dataTable id="modelList" var="model"
            value="#{employeeCategoryBean.list}" paginator="true" rows="10"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" lazy="true" rowKey="#{model.id}"
            selection="#{employeeCategoryBean.selectedModel}"  selectionMode="single"
            widgetVar="modelTable" >

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{employeeCategoryBean.onRowSelect}" />
            <p:ajax event="contextMenu" listener="#{employeeCategoryBean.onRowSelect}" />

            <f:facet name="header">  
                      <p:outputPanel>  
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="modelTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />  
                     </p:outputPanel>  
                </f:facet>


                <p:column  headerText="Name" filterBy="#{employeeCategoryBean.selectedModel.name}" 
                filterStyle="display:none">
                #{model.name}  
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Prefix">
                    #{model.prefix}
                </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: @Daniel.  have you made any changes to code?

Comment: No, just made it all visible (fixed your code indentation)

Comment: @Daniel could u send me the Filtering code for lazy Data Model

Comment: Here an example from primefaces showcase https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/examples/view/LazyCarDataModel.java?r=6171

Answer (score 0):

change

```
filterBy="#{employeeCategoryBean.selectedModel.name}"
```

into

```
filterBy="#{model.name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is on the primefaces page

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf

Answer (score 0):

In Your p:dataTable change lazy="false"